# Rails ERB Text/Password field tooltip on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a password reset form inside which the user has to input password and password confirmation fields.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,
      required: true,
      placeholder: 'Password Confirmation',
      class: 'ctrl',
      title: "should match password" %>
</div>
```

I know since this is a text field, I cannot use "rel" attribute.

If I try to display it with:

```
$(function(){
  $("[rel='nofollow']").tooltip();
});
```

and add these attributes on field:

```
:data => {:toggle=>"tooltip"},
'data-original-title' => "should match password",
'data-placement' => 'right',
rel: 'nofollow'
```

it will only display the title in an ugly way, not as a tooltip.

How can I display the fields' title on focus?

Comment: Have you thought about adding the tooltip to the div wrapping the input field?

Comment: @rsnorman15 can you give me more details about this approach? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the trigger property of tooltip to `focus` on  initialization like this:

```
  $('.text-tooltip').tooltip({
    trigger: 'focus'
  });
```

Add `text-tooltip` class to the input and it should trigger on focus, picking up `title` attribute of the element as the tooltip text.

Comment: it works, the title is being triggered on focus but it looks ugly, I mean it's being displayed as text, no gray/black bubble around the text as in the case of a link/button.

Comment: Do you have complete bootstrap stylesheet included on the page? See if the tooltip work and looks right on a link or a button.

Comment: Works, it was inhibited by some custom css (not written by me but hey).